# mediaPlayer.isPlaying() returns false when i press back and re enter the activity while song is still playing

Tags: java, android

im a beginner and im trying to make a music player app and this code is from the now playing screen's java file

here, the true part of the code runs when i come to this activity by pressing on a bottom now playing bar and the false part is when i come to this activity by clicking on a new song from the list...

now while im on this now playing screen by clicking on a song the mediaplayer works fine
but when i press back and come to the same activity by pressiing on the bottom bar

the mediaplayer says song is not playing (But the song is playing) how to fix this???

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        if(SongName == CurrentSong)  //when bottom bar now playing is clicked
        {

            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "song is still playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "song is not playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        else //when new song from list is clicked
        {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(currentData));
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
```

Comment: You have to stop and kill your media player inside activity `onPause` method. If you want to have media work in the background it's more complicated and requires hosting media player inside of a service.

Answer (score 1):

**It could be because when you reopen the activity you create a new instance of media player which is null and not playing, and you lose the reference for the active mediaplayer.**

**For that keep a reference to your active `mediaplayer` like this:**

**1) Make a class:**

```
public class ActiveMedia{

public static List<MediaPlayer> mediaPlayers = new ArrayList<MediaPlayer>();

}
```

**2) When you start a `mediaplayer` keep its reference in the above static list:**

```
   ...............

    else //when new song from list is clicked
        {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(currentData));
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();

           //here add the mediaplayer instance
           ActiveMedia.mediaPlayers.add(mediaPlayer);

    ..............
```

**3) when you want to come back to activity check active players like this**

```
for(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer : ActiveMedia.mediaPlayers){

if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
//there is an active media player
}else{
//there is no active media player

}

//also you can stop the active mediaplayer or remove ..........

}
```

Comment: Great, if this helped you accept the answer so others know that this is a solution.